# JPA use flush to trigger exception and halt execution

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa

In a recent task, after I created an object I flushed the result to the database. The database table had a unique constraint, meaning that if I tried to flush the same record for the second time, I would get a `ConstraintViolationException`. A sample snippet is shown below:

```java
createEntityAndFlush(result);
sendAsyncRequestToThirdSystem(param);
```

The code for the createEntityAndFlush:

```java
private T createEntityAndFlush(final T entity) throws ServiceException {
    log.debug("Persisting {}", entity.getClass().getSimpleName());
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    getEntityManager().flush();
    return entity;
}
```

The reason I used flush was that I wanted to make sure that a `ConstraintViolationException` would be thrown prior to finishing the transaction and thus calling the `sendAsyncRequestToThirdSystem`. But that was not the case, since `sendAsyncRequestToThirdSystem` was called after the exception was thrown.

To test the code in racing conditions, I used the ManagedExecutorService and created two runnable tasks `(Future<?> submit(Runnable task))` to replicate the incoming request.

Eventually the problem was solved by trying performing a lock on a new table for each unique request id, but I would like to know where I was wrong in my first approach (ex. wrong use of flash, ManagedExecutorService was responsible for awkward behaviour). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that while `flush()` does flush the changes into the database, the transaction is still open, and the unique constraint will be checked when the transaction is **committed** (this may depend on the database, but at least with Postgres and any [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) using DB).

So you will need to make sure that `createEntityAndFlush(result);` runs in its own transaction, possibly with a `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` (or equivalent, if not using Spring) to see if the unique index is violated.